# Doctrine: add ORM configuration file

Tags: php, orm, configuration, doctrine, symfony-2.8

I want to add a custom hydrator in my Symfony 2.8 project. The [official](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#custom-hydration-modes) Doctrine documentation says to add the following code into ORM configuration file.

```
<?php
$em->getConfiguration()->addCustomHydrationMode('CustomHydrator', 'MyProject\Hydrators\CustomHydrator');
```

I have no such file in my project yet, where I should create it and how to include it into my Symfony app?

Comment: Does this help? https://techpunch.co.uk/development/create-custom-doctrine2-hydrator-symfony2

Comment: It does! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find everything you need in the official documentation of Symfony.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html

Symfony is using YAML or XML configuration files for the most bundles. In your case you just need to add the hydrators in `doctrine.orm.entity_managers.YOUR_EM.hydrators`.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your Hydrator file in your Bundle, exemple of path:

```
\Your\Bundle\Hydrators\ListHydrator
```

More information: https://techpunch.co.uk/development/create-custom-doctrine2-hydrator-symfony2